# display inline is not working in ul tag

Tags: html, css

```css
<div class="links1">
    <ul style="float:left; position:absolute; top:115px; right:200px; display:inline;">
        <li><a href="#">Warranty & Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shipping Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want these links to be arranged in horizontal in navigation bar but the `display: inline;` is not working in the `ul` tag please suggest some solution???

Comment: (1) `float` and `display:inline` don't go together. (2) you have to `float` or `inline` your `li`s not the `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `float` and `display:inline` don't go together.
2. You have to `float` or `inline` your `li`s not the `ul`.

***Snippet using `display:inline` or `dsiplay:inline-block` on `li`:***

*Note*: Using only `inline` will prevent `li`s from behaving as block elements thereby preventing you from styling things like dimensions.

```css
div.links1 ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

div.links1 ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="links1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Warranty & Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shipping Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

***Snippet using `float` on `li`:***

*Note*: You have to have adequate margins while `float`ing. This is because, `inline-block` leaves the whitespace in the markup as is and hence you get a small separation between the `li`s.

```css
div.links1 ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Warranty & Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shipping Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed. This is the only answer that actually explains things. Perhaps the downvoter was trying to downvote the question instead, as it is a bit simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<head>
<style>li {display: inline}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="links1">
    <ul >
        <li><a href="#">Warranty & Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shipping Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply `inline` to `li`:

```
li{
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u8shhkem/

Answer (score 0):

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o3apjcku/3/

No need to use `float`, the `li` should be `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block`

```css
.links1 ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="links1">
  <ul style="">
    <li><a href="#">Warranty & Support</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Shipping Info</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check 
http://liveweave.com/cxNlbu

```
   <div class="links1">
    <ul class="hiii">
    <li><a href="#">Warranty & Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shipping Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

css

```
ul.hiii li{display:inline-block;float:left}
```